# SQL Get Text Between \

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm having an issue getting the correct text between characters. I'm currently trying to use SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX. The issue is that the data contains the same identifier. I would like the text that falls between the first '\' and the second '\', removing all the other text. None of the text fields have a fixed number of characters.

Thank you for your help its greatly appreciated.

```
Example
1. Location\Georgia\Atlanta
2. Country\USA\States\Minnesota

Final Result
1. Georgia
2. USA
```

My Current Attempt

```
SUBSTRING(Source,CHARINDEX('\',Source),CHARINDEX('\',Source) - CHARINDEX('\',Source))
```

Comment: delimited text within a column is evil. Sounds like you need either additional columns or an additional table for this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin's answer is slick, this method works, but mostly just illustrates how slick his is:

```
WITH T(Source) AS
(
SELECT 'Location\Georgia\Atlanta' UNION
SELECT 'Country\USA\States\Minnesota'
)
SELECT *, SUBSTRING(Source,CHARINDEX('\',Source)+1,CHARINDEX('\',Source,CHARINDEX('\',Source)+1)-CHARINDEX('\',Source)-1)
FROM T
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Joel's comment. This does look like a violation of [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) but to find the second instance of `\` you can pass the location of the first one in as the third argument to [`CHARINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)

```
WITH T(Source) AS
(
SELECT 'Location\Georgia\Atlanta' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Country\USA\States\Minnesota'
)
SELECT *,
       SUBSTRING(Source, F,CHARINDEX('\',Source, F) - F)
FROM T 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT 1 + CHARINDEX('\',Source)) CA(F)
WHERE Source LIKE '%\%\%'
```

Comment: +1 that you also mentioned joel's comment (cause that data structure seems quite messy to me)

Comment: Yep, I've only had to do this filepaths, never with data structured like that (which is data that should be in separate fields)